# Carbide.c++ 1.2.2 not displaying SDK S60 2nd Edition CW templates

Tags: symbian, carbide

I downloaded Carbide.c++ 1.2 and also downloaded the SDK S60 2nd Edition CW.

I installed the SDK and it is recognized in the Window->Preferences->Carbide C++->SDK preferences.

but when I try to create a new project, the templates related to the SDK aren't displayed.
and the editor seems not to detect the SDK.

has anyone ever experienced this ?

how do you solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Attilah, these are quite old versions of both the SDK and Carbide. But if you need to develop an app for an S60 2nd edition device this makes sense. I don't have either of this installed currently, so it's hard to diagnose exactly.

You said the SDK is recognized. In the SDK preferences, if the checkbox next to the SDK is turned off then the SDK is disabled. Make sure it's enabled.

One thing you could try is to turn of the "Filter templates based on enabled SDKs" checkbox in the new Symbian OS C++ project wizard.

Also, you could try importing one of the example apps from the SDK to confirm you can import and build the project OK.

If you decide to do any work with 3rd or 5th edition phones then you can get the latest Carbide from http://developer.symbian.org/main/tools_and_kits/downloads/view.php?id=2